# How to present vertical separators on a horizontal `FlatList`?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

[image]

I’m using React Native’s new `FlatList` component. I’m using it to present an **horizontal** list, but when using the built-in `ItemRenderComponent` it presents the separators **beneath** each items, instead of in between.

Is there a way to change that?

```
 interface State {
dataSource: WhosOutByPolicy[];
}

interface Props {
 data: WhosOutByPolicy[];
}

class WhosOutParentCell extends Component<Props, State> {
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { dataSource: props.data };
}

renderSeparator = () => {
    return (
        <View
            style={{
                height: 100,
                width: 3,
                backgroundColor: "#D81458"
            }}
        />
    );
};

render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <FlatList
                data={this.state.dataSource}
                horizontal={true}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                    <WhosOutUsersInPolicyCell data={item} />
                )}
                keyExtractor={item => item.policyDispalyName}
                ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
            />
        </View>
    );
   }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#EFEFEF"
}
});

export default WhosOutParentCell;
```

Comment: Put the code for your render, renderRow and renderSeperator. How do you expect us to know your problem??

Comment: update your question with your code please.

Comment: @KhalilKhalaf, I updated the question with the relevant code

Comment: @VahidBoreiri - I added it

Comment: I am worried about the hieght:100 thing, can you add a print screen too? Also do you a lot of items and "_have_" to use a flatlist? Why not listView?

Comment: Why should the height: 100 make a difference? Also, even if I change it to 5 it acts the same (except that the height decreases)

Comment: @KhalilKhalaf As far as I understand, `FlatList` is the current recommendation, and yes, it need to be able to handle lots of items

Comment: @KhalilKhalaf added a screenshot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a `react-native` bug that is not fixed yet. You can rewrite your code as blow to solve this problem:

```
renderSeparator = () => {
    return (
      <View
        style = {{
          height: 100,
          width: 3,
          backgroundColor: '#D81458'
        }}
      />
    )
  }         

_renderItem = ({item, index}) => (
  <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
    <WhosOutUsersInPolicyCell data = { item } />
    {(index !== this.state.dataSource.length - 1) && this.renderSeparator()}
  </View>
)

render() {
  return (
    <View style = { styles.container } >
      <FlatList
        data = { this.state.dataSource }
        horizontal = { true }
        renderItem = {this._renderItem}
        keyExtractor = { item => item.policyDispalyName }
      />
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: Vahid, yes, this what I thought. THANK YOU!

Comment: Happy to help you.

Comment: Vahid, just a small typo: a `()` are missing after `this.renderSeperator`.